# Why can't I open this csv file I downloaded and what are these errors?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and I was beginning to run a simple code to work with this CSV file I downloaded from the government portal. Here's my code -

> import pandas as pd
>     df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek')
>
> print(df.head)

The path is correct and it didn't work without adding the r at the beginning so I used that. However, this code results in these errors and I'm not sure how to handle any of them.
[image]

I've opened the file on Excel and I don't think there's any problem with it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the file name? `pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek\filename.xlsx')` Also, do you the required permission to read from the path?

Comment: please validate what @meW said, also do you have the file open? Windows can raise that exception when the file you are manipulating is open.

Comment: Ah so that's what this was all about. Yes, thank you. I hadn't included the filename itself.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have permission to open the file. Run your interpreter as administrator, or adjust permissions.

Right click your python shell and select "run as administrator".